# HTML and Javascript with Joomla

Tags: javascript, html, joomla

Trying to solve a simple problem: have 2 input fields (Joomla XML defined), the sum of both should be presented in a third field as soon as the input in the second field is made. The first two fields go through a validation routine (client-side). Both first fields have an attribute "validate" that go through an javascript file using regex. How can I transfer the "sum" to my HTML page? Thks in advance.

Comment: Tried to integrate in the validation js:                      
        document.formvalidator.setHandler('startblock',
                function (value)                
                {
                        regex = /^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]$/;
                        return regex.test(value);
                });

Comment: Question details all belong in the question itself.

Comment: Joomla questions posted at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange are infinitely more likely to get answered by someone who actually uses Joomla and are infinitely less likely to get casually downvoted.